# 3 different funcs launched as goroutines produce the same goroutine (apparently ignore arguments)

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

For 3 different and distinct "c"

```
for _, c := range u.components { // u.components has 3 members
    fmt.Printf("%v %v", c.name, c.channel) // prints 3 distinct name/channel pairs 
    go c.Listen(); // a method of c that listens on channel c.channel
}
```

...launches 3 identical goroutines in which c.name and c.channel are identical.

The long version (commented, short code):
https://play.golang.org/p/mMQb_5jLjm

This is my first Go program, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `c.Listen()` is closing around the value of c, which is passed via a pointer to `Listen`, and each iteration changes that value. It's easier to visualize if you look at the method call as a method expression

```
go (*component).Listen(&c)
```

https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Create a new value for c on each iteration to prevent the previous from being overwritten:

```
for _, c := range u.components { // u.components has 3 members
    c := c
    fmt.Printf("%v %v", c.name, c.channel) // prints 3 distinct name/channel pairs 
    go c.Listen(); // a method of c that listens on channel c.channel
}
```

Or use the value contained in the slice directly:

```
for i := range u.components {
    go u.components[i].Listen()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix and especially for the explanation. It works properly now.